# How to show user status (offline, online) in agora during a video call in android

Tags: java, android, offline, agora.io, videocall

I just want to know the method in agora I can use to get the status when user is online or offline during a video call.
I am using onUseroffline() method but i can't get status when user is online.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved.
Basically we have to wait 20 seconds for user to go offline.
After 20 seconds onUserOffline() is called and when user rejoins onUserjoined() is called.